# Hungry Backspace in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, ide, editor

In some editors there exist plugins implementing a feature called "hungry backspace" or "hungry delete".

If this mode is active in a text editor then one hit to the backspace key will automatically delete all whitespace chars backwards from the current cursor position up to the first non-whitespace character.

For example, this feature exists for [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/Hungry-WS-Deletion.html) and [IntelliJ IDEA](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=162).

Does anyone know if it is also available in Eclipse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alt-Del is probably as close as you're going to get without writing a plugin yourself.  Others have asked for this feature (coming from intelliJ) but so far it doesn't exist, or it's not published.

-Adam

Comment: What is it supposed to do? In my Eclipse 3.4.1, it does nothing.

Comment: Do you mean ctrl+del, which deletes the next word?

Answer (score 2):

CTRL-backspace is pretty close too: **delete previous word**:

```
function();    (4 spaces)
```

+ CTRL-BACKSPACE gives:

```
function
```

Other than that, **[AnyEdit](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/anyedit/index.html)** plugin can convert trailing spaces into tabs (but also into "", effectively removing them)

Comment: Delete previous word is rather Ctrl+Backspace. Ctrl+Delete is Delete next word...
At least on my copy.

Answer (score 1):

**Ctrl+Shift+Left, Backspace** always works for me. works in notepad, web browsers, everywhere.
Stick to the standards :)

Comment: Yes I use these patterns very much. But this one selects text up to the beginning of the previosu word. That's a little annoying since I only want to delete up to the end of that word.

Answer (score 0):

In SciTE, and Eclipse (3.4), Ctrl+Shift+Del with the caret after the last visible character will delete these spaces. Ie. it deletes from caret to end of line.

Actually, in SciTE I don't need to do that, since I have set it up to automatically remove these trailing spaces when saving.

Note: In Preferences > General > Keys, there is a Remove Trailing Whitespace binding (without key assignment by default) which seems to apply to File.

Comment: CTRL + ALT + ... DEL ? On my windows desktop, it does not delete anything, but it does bring the logon screen, asking me if I want to lock my session ;)

Comment: Whoops! It was Ctrl+Shift+Del, of course! :-D Everybody can make a typo... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

From eclipse Windows menu/Preferences
Search for Keys and filter to "Delete Previous Word"and Bind it to the Ctrl+Backspace
[image]